# ReferenceError: performance is not defined

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to debug a really bizarre browser javascript error:

```
ReferenceError: performance is not defined
at _s.monitor (path_to_bundle.js:1:148100)
```

(left only latest stack frame)

The code at 1:148100 looks like this:

```
monitor(){window.performance&&"undefined"!=typeof performance&&(actual body of the method)}
                 ^
                 ReferenceError: performance is not defined
```

I thought I understand javascript, and `window.performance` should never result in ReferenceError if `window` is defined and equals to global window object in browser. But somehow this error is thrown many hundred times per day on different User Agents, and I have no idea what is going on here.

Please advise, how to debug or maybe there is a sneaky browser feature I don't know about.

Upd: website this error is happening on is using Svelte.

Comment: The code you've shown *cannot* throw this error. It would only make sense if it came from reading a variable called `performance` and that variable did not exist. The code is reading the *property* `performance` from `window`. That cannot result in this ReferenceError

Comment: @VLAZ that's what I thought as well, but my observability tool captures a stack trace and the first frame in it points to this exact code. This is a mystery how it is possible. I will update the post if I find a reason.

Comment: @VLAZ just found out the website this error happens on is using Svelte, potentially SSR as well. Perhaps this is SSR related.